# adding class to button when another element is scrolled into the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one static button and one element which scrolls. When the scrollable element enters the browser viewport, I want the static button to get a class (e.g. underline). 
I have this now, but it doesn't work:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + jQuery(window).height();

    var elemTop = jQuery(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + jQuery(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    jQuery('#my-scrolling-element').each(function () {
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
            jQuery('#my-static-button').addClass('my-class');
        }
    });

});
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Did you debug in steps to see if the numbers are correct? is it calling the isScrolledIntoView() function? how many scrolling elements do you have? You cannot have multiple elements with same ID. Id is meant to be unique so your .each() will not go through all the elements that has the same ID, only the first one.

Comment: I did not debug, because I don't know how to, unfortunately. I have several scrolling elements but I am aware that they have to be unique, so there is no double id.

Comment: Try this code


jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    element = jQuery('#my-scrolling-element');
        if (isScrolledIntoView(element) === true) {
            jQuery('#my-static-button').addClass('my-class');
        }
});

Comment: @HarsimranjitSingh this works! Thanks! I added else, like this: jQuery(window).scroll(function () { element = jQuery('#my-scrolling-element'); if (isScrolledIntoView(element) === true) { jQuery('#my-static-button').addClass('my-class'); } else { jQuery('#my-static-button').removeClass('my-class'); } });

At first, the class didn't react on the right position. As a test, I gave five elements the id #my-scrolling-element and now it works perfectly! But how can that be, I thought it wouldn't work if the scrolling element wasn't unique. Maybe only the button has to be unique? Anyways, fantastic!

Comment: @skt when you write $(this) it means it points to the currently actioned element. so no need to worry about unique, jquery take cares of it.

Comment: Ah, I see! Should we then post this code as a solution? You have the credit for it so maybe you should post it? Otherwise I can add your name to the answer if I post it.

Comment: @HarsimranjitSingh I am having some problems. 1) The class only gets added on certain textblocks, it doesn't work on a shape. 2) I told you it works if several elements have the same id, which was strange and obviously some bug. Now, my CMS automatically adds _number to each id. For example #my-scrolling-element_9544. How can I write, in JavaScript, jQuery('#my-scrolling-element+whatever ending')???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to add class to the element that is input type then below code will work.

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  element = jQuery('#my-scrolling-element');
  if (isScrolledIntoView(element) === true) {
    jQuery('#my-static-button')
    //if the type of element is input then it will work.
    $("input[id^='my-scrolling-element_']").addClass('my-class');
  } else {
    jQuery('#my-static-button').removeClass('my-class');
  }
});

//OR 
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  element = jQuery('#my-scrolling-element');
  if (isScrolledIntoView(element) === true) {
    jQuery('#my-static-button').addClass('my-class');
  } else {
    jQuery('#my-static-button').removeClass('my-class');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is perfect! I can add that the function must be included before. 

Additionally, to overcome a lot of strange problems that might occur, I use jQuery('#my-scrolling-element1, #my-scrolling-element2, #my-scrolling-element3')

or cleaner, which didn't work for me but should work:
jQuery("[id^='#my-scrolling-element']")

Comment: @ankitkanojia what did you improved by editing my code ?

Comment: I was a bit too fast there. The multiple selector of IDs has no effect in my case, but it should work. Why?

Comment: if your ID starts with same characters then it should definitely work.  --  $("input[id^='my-scrolling-element_']").addClass('my-class');

Comment: yes. It is very strange. Must be something with the Slider Revolution 6. Have to ask them I suppose.

Comment: for example, the SR6 doesn*t understand $, I have to write jQuery instead. What if it doesn't understand ^ either? What could I write instead as JavaScript for RS6?

Comment: @HarsimranjitSingh, The alignement was not proper so just update the POST with proper alignment. nothing else.